# jQuery Ajax PHP issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Probably a duplicate of a question somewhere, but I don't care. I've tried googling, but have not found an answer.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#foo").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       cache   : false,
       url     : "map.php?map=refresh",
       data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
       success: function(data) {
        $("#container").html(data); 
       }
      });
});
});
```

I've tried `.click(function() {`, `.sumbit(function() {`, `.bind("submit", function() {`, and I believe others.

```
<form id="foo">
    <div id="inner"><input id="move" name="left" type="button" value="LEFT" /></div>
    <div id="inner"><input id="move" name="right" type="button" value="RIGHT" /></div>
    <div id="inner"><input id="move" name="down" type="button" value="DOWN" /></div>
    <div id="inner"><input id="move" name="up" type="button" value="UP" /></div>
</form>
```

I've got `<div id="container" style="width:660px; height:660px;">` which contains a lot of stuff, but I'd just like it to be replaced:
    WORKED

Comment: $("#foo").click(function()  is wrong.try $("#foo input").click(function()

Comment: MIIB is right. And use $("#foo").on('click', function()... and not $("#foo").click(function()... Form is not clickable. The button and others elements IN this form are clickables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#foo").submit(function() {` should work but if you are going to go the for `.click` event handler you want it to be on the inputs.  So rather than doing this

```
$("#foo").click(function() {
```

You need to do

```
$("#foo input").click(function() {
```

Also you'll need to stop the default event so the page doesn't refresh.  This could be where you are going wrong.  So you need to do

```
$("#foo input").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Ajax call
});
```

**Please note** you all of your input field contain the same id of "move" which will invalidate the HTML

Comment: I've changed the id's to move1, move2, etc. I changed the names to "l", "r", "d", and "u" since I had some anchors with id's of "left", "right", etc. (just in case there was some issue there). I've also  changed it to $("#foo input").click(function() {, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: What happens if you do an `alert('here')` inside of your .click function?  Does it work?  Also does the page refresh?

Comment: alert('here'); does nothing. No page refreshes.

Comment: try adding method and action attributes to your form like `<form id="foo" method="post" action="">`

Comment: <form id="foo" method="post" action="map.php?map=refresh">....still nothing. If I change the buttons to submits, then it refreshes the page, but doesn't change the div.

Comment: After trying the code on a fresh page, it worked. So the error lies in some other JS on the page I need it to be on...